# DDD Symfony / Doctrine library - Security User needs UserInterface

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, domain-driven-design

What the title basically means is this:

tldr; My User **Domain** model, which should not have any relation to the **Application** layer, needs the UserInterface (a Symfony class) for Symfony Security to work.

My setup is as follows:

```
app/
...
src/
vendor/
```

"app" contains all the pure Symfony code that uses all the "Domain" related code from "src"

"src" contains a Domain that has a structure like so:

```
DomainName/Application
DomainName/Domain
DomainName/Infrastructure
```

The "User" model (plain old php object) defined within DomainName/Domain SHOULD NOT implement/extend code from the Application layer. But I can't get it to work. I have looked into extending and providing a "different" User model (from within "app") and mappedSuperclasses of Doctrine, but my model has too many relations for that to work.

Is this setup even possible or should I accept this is the only way to go? :(

NB: I hope it is kinda clear what I'm trying to achieve, it's difficult to explain.

Full example layout:

```
app/

config/security.yaml
    security:
      ...
      providers:
        app_user_provider:
          entity:
            class: DomainName\Domain\User

src/DomainName/Domain/User.php
    - Nothing special, id, uuid, etc

src/DomainName/Domain/Repository/UserRepository.php
    - This is an interface, because the domain does not contain the implementation

src/DomainName/Infrastructure/Persistence/Doctrine/Dbal/UserDbalRepository.php
    - This implements the UserRepository, and the UserRepository will always be injected within "app"

src/DomainName/Infrastructure/Persistence/Doctrine/ORM/User.orm.yml
    - This is the mapping ORM file for the Entity
```

Comment: Hi. Personally, I use an interface in my domain, which is implemented in infrastructure.

Comment: in /Core/Domain/Gateway/Repository/UserRepositoryInterface.php
my interface UserRepositoryInterface{public function getAll(): Collection;}
and in /Infrastructure/Repository/UserRepository.php its implementation
class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface, UserLoaderInterface{public function getAll(): Collection{}}

Comment: You can really tie yourself up in knots trying to implement DDD but at the same time using Symfony specific functionality.  Why should the Symfony authorization layer need to know about your domain objects?  Not really very DDD like.  If you really want a DDD entity to be independent of Symfony stuff then you probably need to introduce a mapping layer.  You will also probably encounter plenty of other issues with doctrine such as Doctrine collections.  Bottom line: DDD entities are not the same as Doctrine/Symfony entities.

Comment: Effectively, afterwards it is necessary, at the very least, to transform the doctrine entities into business entities.

Comment: @Monnomcjo I need the User model to be known to Symfony Security for the firewall to work, and for that I need the UserInterface (supplied by Symfony). I can't seem to figure out how to prevent Domain/Infrastructure mixture. It feels like you are right. Fully implementing DDD is a hard task in this situation and I should just accept this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit old topic, but for other people who will face similiar issue I had exactly same case in my current project, and I solved it by creating Domain User Model and in Infrastructure I have created SecurityUser model, with dependency of my User model from Domain, so I was able to use my Domain UserRepository eg. in custom user provider from which I was returnig SecurityUser, with injected Domain User fetched from repository.